# SwiftUI New File and Passing a value

Tags: variables, swiftui

I have a value as $freq being passed to a new SwiftUI file as frequencyValue, however the file called DipoleView is getting the error below.

This is in the ContentView:

```
   HStack{
        NavigationLink(destination: DipoleView(frequencyValue: $freq)) {
          Text("Dipole")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: 150.00, height: 50.0)
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(25)
            .shadow(radius: 10.0)
            .padding()
        }
```

The code below is at the base of the other file called DipoleView and it requires some code concerning the passing of the variable from the ContentView..

```
#if DEBUG
struct DipoleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    **DipoleView(frequencyValue: <#Binding<String>#>)**
  }
}
#endif
```

The above DipoleView(frequencyValue: <#Binding#>) I need to place some code here but I am not sure what it is suppose to be?

Hoping someone can help a Newby.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just trying to create a preview, you can use a constant binding:

```swift
#if DEBUG
struct DipoleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DipoleView(frequencyValue: .constant("some frequency value"))
    }
}
#endif
```

This makes the binding immutable in your preview, but you shouldn't really need a mutable binding when previewing in the canvas.

Comment: Thank you graycampbell much appreciated !